# How do I sign a JWT using ES256?

Tags: pyjwt, jwcrypto

I am trying to sign using `pyjwt`

```
key = jwk.JWK.from_pem(pkey_contents)
token = jwt.JWT(header={"alg": "ES256"},
                     claims=Token.serialize())
token.make_encrypted_token(key)
```

and I am getting this error

```
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwcrypto/jwe.py", line 122, in _jwa_keymgmt
app_1         |     raise InvalidJWEOperation('Algorithm not allowed')
app_1         | jwcrypto.common.InvalidJWEOperation: Algorithm not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `make_encrypted_token` with `make_signed_token`

Make encrypted_token **encrypts** the end token whereas ES256 is used to **sign** the token.